# Error when use BroadcastReceiver on Android

Tags: android

I create code for pop-up incoming message with Android Studio. I'm used this code for BroadcastReceiver

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver
```

and already setup in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">
```

but on my BroadcastReceiver get error message

```
Error:(12, 8) error: class IncomingSms is public, should be declared in a 
file named IncomingSms.java
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

someone know how to correct declare for this?

Comment: Can you check file extension of `IncomingSms`?

Comment: As the error says put your class in a seperate file named IncomingSms

Comment: @cokceken how to do that?

Comment: @AndiGeeky Yeah, the is option Make 'IncomingSms' not public, when i choice that "public" is deleted and being class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver, so get other error

Comment: right click to project tree -> new -> Java file. Name it IncomingSms and put your class definition in it

Comment: @cokceken ok, already done. i put the code to right correct class as you sugest.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java file need to have THE SAME name as the main class in it. That is the problem

[image: Java file with the same name as the class name]

Comment: ok, already done. i put the code to right class. btw your image can't to open

Comment: The image it's been uploaded with stackoverflow form, so... I don't know..